# What kind of Visualization is this?

Tags: visualization, plotting

Can anyone help identify what kind of Visualization this is? 
(google image search was not informative, unfortunately...)

[image]

Comment: [Sankey diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram). You can make them with [d3](https://github.com/d3/d3-sankey).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site!

I think it is called as **Flow Visualization**. I remember seeing something similar when I was running a Campaign using Google Analytics. That graph is used for showing the Click-Path Analysis, Visit Flow, Navigation Flow etc. You can go through this [link-1](http://cutroni.com/blog/2011/10/19/path-analysis-in-google-analytics-with-flow-visualization/), [link-2](https://www.e-nor.com/blog/general/google-analytics-flow-visualization-not-your-traditional-path-analysis) for better understanding.

The outcome of this graph was to see which path was mostly used and where can we find some room to improve it the ones which are not used mostly, finding the root cause and provide best experience to the users.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? if yes, can you accept the answer. Thanks in advance.